# Set the keys of an array according to another one's values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$array1 = array( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 [6] => 9 ) ;

$array2 = array( ( [0] => Array (...) [1] => Array (...) [2] => Array (...) ... [6] => Array (...));
```

They have the same number of elements. I want the array2 to have, as keys, the values of array1.

Should become:

```
 $array2 = array( ( [2] => Array (...) [3] => Array (...) [5] => Array (...) ... [9] => Array (...));
```

I have written this code but, I dunno why it returns only a part of array2.

```
reset($array1);reset($array2);
foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
   unset ($array2[$k]);

   $new_key =  current($array1);
   next($array1);
   $array2[$new_key] = $v;
}
print_r($array2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You perhaps could try using array_flip() on both of your arrays. After that you use array_combine()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_combine` to create an object with keys from one array, and the values from another.

```
$array_1 = array ('hello','world','stackoverflow');
$array_2 = array (
  array ('greetings'),
  array ('planet'),
  array ('websitefilledwithgeeks')
);

print_r (
  array_combine ($array_1, $array_2)
);
```

output

```
    Array
(
    [hello] => Array
        (
            [0] => greetings
        )

    [world] => Array
        (
            [0] => planet
        )

    [stackoverflow] => Array
        (
            [0] => websitefilledwithgeeks
        )

)
```

---

Documentation of [PHP: array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)